# Swift: How to access in AppDelegate variable from the View controller?

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I would like to write in the text or csv (prefer) file the variable from the view controller.

Indeed I am doing a drawing app and I would like to write in the file the current position of the finger.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {var lastPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint ... }
```

I would like to have access to lastPoint.x and lastPoint.y from the AppDelegate. how I could do that ?  Thank you.

Comment: Where and how is your ViewController created ?

Answer (score 42):

Your question is full of confusion but if that's what you are looking for:

**You can access the appDelegate by getting a reference to it like that:**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

after that if you have store a property called lastPoint in your appDelegate you can access its components very simply like that:

```
let x = appDelegate.lastPoint.x
let y = appDelegate.lastPoint.y
```

**If you need to access your viewController properties from the AppDelegate, then I suggest having a reference to your view controller in your appdelegate:**

```
var myViewController: ViewController!
```

then when your view controller is created you can store a reference to it in the appdelegate property:

If your create your view controller outside of your appDelegate:

**Swift 1-2 syntax**

```
var theViewController = ViewController()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.myViewController = theViewController
```

**Swift 3-4 syntax**

```
var theViewController = ViewController()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.myViewController = theViewController
```

If you create your view controller inside of your appDelegate:

```
self.myViewController = ViewController()
```

After that you can access your data from your viewcontroller from your appdelegate just by accessing its property like that:

```
let x = self.myViewController.lastPoint.x
let y = self.myViewController.lastPoint.y
```

Comment: Actually it s the opposite that I need. From appDelegate I need to have access to variable lastPoint.x and lastPoint.y (found in the ViewController)

Comment: it s doesn't work. There is a mistake at this line:
appDelegate.myViewController = theViewController

"expected declaration"

And the also : let x = self.myViewController.lastPoint.x
let y = self.myViewController.lastPoint.y

Comment: Could you tell us where you put those lines ?

Comment: inside: 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {...}
(instead of 3 dots) because I want to use X and Y in the application function.

Comment: All of this needs to be declared in the body of the function. You can put this in applicationDidFinishLaunching for example or in a custom function that you can call when your ViewController has been created

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 Update**

```
    var theViewController = ViewController()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.myViewController = theViewController
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a BaseViewController and write this

```
class BaseViewController {
  lazy var appDelegate : AppDelegate {
     return UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
  }
}
```

and inherit other viewcontrollers with BaseViewController and access this by

```
class ViewController : BaseViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(self.appDelegate?.lastPoint.x)
    print(self.appDelegate?.lastPoint.x)
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to access my ViewController from the App delegate by creating an instance of ViewController in AppDelegate.swift, like:

```
var mainViewController = ViewController()

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    mainViewController.myVariable = "Hello".
}
```

Still, I don't understand how does the AppDelegate "know" that mainViewController is supposed to point to that particular ViewController. As my application has a single view and a single ViewController, that's fine, but what it I had multiple ViewControllers associated with different UIViews? Appreciate if anyone here can shed a light into that.
Best Regards,
Andre

Comment: Just found out that AppDelegate is not referencing my actual ViewController.swift. It seems to have created a new ViewController instance inside my AppDelegate, so I still don't know how to access my existing VC instance. Appreciate any clarification on this topic.

Comment: Just found this response to what I need here in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831571/swift-ios-how-to-run-function-in-viewcontroller-from-appdelegate