# swift ios - How to run function in ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, function, appdelegate, func

I am trying to run a function in certain `ViewController` using `AppDelegate`

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        ViewController().grabData()
}
```

But somehow the function does not seem to run at all when the app has become active after entering the app from the background.

The function looks like this

```
func grabData() {
        self._DATASERVICE_GET_STATS(completion: { (int) -> () in
            if int == 0 {
                print("Nothing")
            } else {
                print(int)

                for (_, data) in self.userDataArray.enumerated() {
                    let number = Double(data["wage"]!)
                    let x = number!/3600
                    let z = Double(x * Double(int))
                    self.money += z
                    let y = Double(round(1000*self.money)/1000)

                    self.checkInButtonLabel.text = "\(y) KR"
                }

                self.startCounting()
                self.workingStatus = 1
            }
        })
    }
```

And uses this var

```
var money: Double = 0.000
```

What have I missed?

**Thanks!**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34745677/2303865

Comment: Is the *certain* view controller the initial view controller? If yes create a property in `AppDelegate` and assign the reference to that view controller to the property. If not – the other way round – in `viewDidLoad()` of the *certain* controller get the AppDelegate instance and assign the reference from there. `Notification` is most likely not needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ViewController().grabData()` will create a new instance of the ViewController and call this function. Then.. as the view controller is not in use it will be garbage collected/removed from memory. You need to be calling this method on the actual view controller that is in use. Not a new instance of it.

The best option would be to listen for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification that iOS provides.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(grabData),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
    object: nil)
```

make sure that you also remove the observer, this is usually done in a `deinit` method

```
deinit() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: When should I remove the observer?

Comment: deinit is usually the best place to remove it. this means that as the view controller is de-initialised (released from memory) then it removes itself as an observer. I used to do this in viewDidUnload but this has been deprecated now

Answer (score 3):

I simply solved it like this:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! ViewController
        viewController.grabData()
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. You should use the method posted by Scriptable

Comment: If sometime you will need to do things like reload a `tableview` I thing that your app will crash